# How to extract clusters using OPTICS ( R package - dbscan , or alternatives )

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, optics-algorithm

This might be a mix of a R question and an algorithm question. The question is about both OPTICS in general and the R implementation of optics in the package "dbscan" ( https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dbscan/dbscan.pdf )

My main reason to move from using DBSCAN to OPTICS was that the dataset I have has variable density clusters, and they are of irregular shape. OPTICS produces a reachability plot, but for my use case the more interesting part is the extraction of clusters. There is some automatic cluster extraction described in the original paper that isn't just a single cut-point for eps. ( http://fogo.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/Publikationen/Papers/OPTICS.pdf).

So my two part qn: 
1) Is there a way to use the R package in this way for the automatic extraction?
2) Is there an OPTICS implementation that supports this (python,elsewhere)?

Comment: ELKI has automatic extraction, and the most flexible OPTICS implementation. In particular, it works well with geodata and custom distance functions.

Comment: Thanks Anony-Mousse. I will try ELKI out and/or write my own cluster extraction code in R.

Comment: ELKI worked great..though it did turn out that OPTICSXi couldn't really handle my dataset all that well. My suspicion is that it had something to do with the fact that my clusters are asymmetric, they start out dense on side of my 2d plot and become sparser as you move to another. Also, the cluster structures shows lots and lots of little islands, each of different density as well as spacing. In any case, ELKI helped me determine that OPTICS can only do so much. Thanks for the guidance!

Comment: I think this is normal that it is only steep on the left. If you have many small islands, you may need a larger minpts? It would maybe help if you could share your OPTICS plot.

Comment: Sorry about the late response -- it wasn't a chart I could share unfortunately, so I didn't post it. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

1) Yes!  The dbscan package has a function to extract optics clusters with variable density.  `?dbscan::extractXi()`

> extractXi extract clusters hiearchically specified in Ankerst et al (1999) based on the steepness of the reachability plot. One interpretation of the xi parameter is that it classifies clusters by change in relative cluster density. The used algorithm was originally contributed by the ELKI framework, but contains a set of fixes.

See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dbscan/vignettes/dbscan.pdf for extensive description of methods and examples